# What does update() in mongodb returns

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

While writing python script for the api in mongodb..

We have..

```
new_posts = [{ 'name': 'A', 'age': 17, 'marks': 97, 'school': 'School1' },
             { 'name': 'B', 'age': 18, 'marks': 95, 'school': 'School2' },
             { 'name': 'C', 'age': 19, 'marks': 97, 'school': 'School2' }]

db.posts.insert( new_posts )
```

We create indexes as follows..

```
db.posts.create_index([('name',1),('school',1)],unique=True)
```

Now we perform two operations..

```
db.posts.update({ 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'school': 'School3' },
                { 'name':'D', 'age':  17, 'marks': 70, 'school': 'School1' },
                   upsert=True )

db.posts.update({ 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'school': 'School1' },  
                { 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'marks': 60, 'school': 'School1' },
                   upsert=True )
```

What does the update() returns here? How can we find out weather the document is inserted into the db or existing document is updated?

Can we do something like..

```
post1 = db.posts.update({ 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'school': 'School3' },
                        { 'name':'D', 'age':  17, 'marks': 70, 'school': 'School1' },
                        upsert=True )

post2 = db.posts.update({ 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'school': 'School1' },
                        { 'name':'A', 'age': 17, 'marks': 60, 'school': 'School1' },
                           upsert=True )

print post1

print post2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) for `update` say, the method returns:

> A document (dict) describing the effect of the update or `None` if write acknowledgement is disabled.

Just try it and `print` the return value to see what's available.  You'll see something like:

```
{u'syncMillis': 0, u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'writtenTo': None,
 u'connectionId': 190, u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': True}
```

The `updatedExisting` field is what you're looking for.